# Can I use C/C++ code inside my ActionScript-3 code?

Tags: c++, c, actionscript-3

I wonder if there is ways for communicate actionscript with c/c++, as well as the level of complexity..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [Adobe Labs Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/):

> Welcome the preview release of codename "Alchemy." Alchemy is a research project that allows users to compile C and C++ code that is targeted to run on the open source ActionScript Virtual Machine (AVM2). The purpose of this preview is to assess the level of community interest in reusing existing C and C++ libraries in Web applications that run on Adobe® Flash® Player and Adobe AIR®.

Comment: thanks for answering! But it's just a "preview release".. is there something really mature?

Comment: You should still check out alchemy, some people have done some pretty cool stuff with it! You might also want to check out http://haxe.org/ I know there is some sort of C/C++ support or something, might be a good idea to look into it, not sure how relevant it is though.

Comment: @Tom: I've been messing around with Alchemy recently.  It has given me a lot of trouble, but I've been able to get some results out of it.  It's primarily for C, with any C++ support being pretty much incidental.

Comment: @ __dominic Haxe basicaly has the ability to translate the HaXe code (basically AS3) into C++ code :)